# Ubuntu getting every line after match

Tags: 16.04

By using:

```
egrep -w -R -i -B1 -A1 'username|url|query' testlog
```

I can only get one line after match. I want to use this code as script some file may have more than 10k line data stored in a files

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` instead of `grep`:

```
sed -e '/username|url|query/,$p' testlog
```